# Javascript change scr on iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a problem with my code.  I want to change the iframe url when the submit button is clicked, but it isn't working.  I have found some questions about this, and I found GoToGoogle function where it must forward to google.  So that's all of my code for the page.

```
<script>
function sendMeToGoogle(){
document.getElementId('changeme').src="http://google.com/";
}
</script>
this is test

<iframe src="test" ID="changeme" ></iframe>
<input type="submit" onclick="sendMeToGoogle();" />
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: cross domain is not allowed....

Comment: You make a mistake - document.getElementById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not calling the right Javascript function. You should be calling

`document.getElementById` but instead you are calling `document.getElementId` which doesn't exist.